# How can I include the information from my database in firestore the mail I send through Mailer?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mailer

currently I can read the information stored in my database displayed in my application but what I want now is with a button to send that information by email for mailer and I managed to implement that by pressing the "alert" button I send an email but I can not find how to do so that the stored information is sent as I show it.

Here is my code of how I show the information that the user enters the database through a form and this is where I show it.

```
                          class _readDataState extends State<readData> {
                        final Stream<QuerySnapshot> users = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('users')
                            .orderBy('Fecha ingreso sintoma', descending: true)
                            .snapshots();

                        deletedata(id) async {
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).delete();
                        }

                        @override
                        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                          return Scaffold(
                              appBar: AppBar(
                                title: Text('Sintomas'),
                                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 57, 137),
                                elevation: 0.0,
                              ),
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 730,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                        stream: users,
                                        builder: (
                                          BuildContext context,
                                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
                                        ) {
                                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                            return Text('Algo salio mal');
                                          }
                                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                            return Text('Cargando');
                                          }
                                          final data = snapshot.requireData;
                                          return ListView.builder(
                                            itemCount: data.size,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                              return Card(
                                                child: Column(
                                                  //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Text('Síntomas'),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${data.docs[index]['Fecha ingreso sintoma']}',
                                                    ),
                                                    Text('''
                                                        Fatiga: ${data.docs[index]['Fatiga'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Miccion: ${data.docs[index]['Miccion'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Flujo Vaginal: ${data.docs[index]['Flujo Vaginal'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Estreñimiento:  ${data.docs[index]['Estreñimiento'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Acidez Gastrica: ${data.docs[index]['Acidez Gastrica'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Sangrado Nasal: ${data.docs[index]['Sangrado Nasal'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Sangrado de encias: ${data.docs[index]['Sangrado de encias'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Hinchazon: ${data.docs[index]['Hinchazon'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        Problemas respiratarios: ${data.docs[index]['Problemas respiratarios'] ? "Si" : "No"}
                                                        '''),
                                                    Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                        children: [
                                                          TextButton(
                                                            child: Text("¡Alertar!"),
                                                            onPressed: sendEmail,
                                                          ),
                                                          GestureDetector(
                                                            onTap: () {
                                                              deletedata(data.docs[index].id);
                                                              setState(() {});
                                                            },
                                                            child: Icon(
                                                              Icons.delete,
                                                              color: Colors.red,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ]),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                elevation: 6,
                                                shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 57, 137),
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                                shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        }
```

This is where I sent the email and I already tried adding the information to the text but it does not allow me

```
              Future sendEmail() async {
                  final user = await GoogleAuthApi.signIn();

                  if (user == null) return;

                  final email = user.email;
                  final auth = await user.authentication;
                  final token = auth.accessToken!;

                  print('Authenticated: $email');
                  GoogleAuthApi.signOut();

                  final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2(email, token);
                  final message = Message()
                    ..from = Address(email, 'Aplicacion contro embarazos alto riesgo!')
                    ..recipients = ['gx_13@hotmail.com']
                    ..subject = '¡¡Alerta!! '
                    ..html =
                        '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>HTML</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css"></head><body><p>Esta página web es una página HTML válida.</p></body></html>';
                  //..text = '';

                  try {
                    await send(message, smtpServer);

                    showSnackBar('sAlerta Enviada');
                  } on MailerException catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                }

                void showSnackBar(String text) {
                  final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: Text(
                      text,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  );
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                    ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
                }
              }
```

This is how it looks in the app. in the alert button the mail is sent

[image]

and this is how the mail arrives

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where the alert button is instead of "onPressed: sendEmail" you put "onPressed: () => sendEmail(data)" in the sendEmail function the parameters are added and they can be used to include the database data data in the mail

```
onPressed: () => sendEmail(data, index),

Future sendEmail(QuerySnapshot<Object?> data, index) async {
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).